# How to target label with a sibling of input with :has() selector?

Tags: css

I want to use :has() to selectively target `<label>` with an `<input>` sibling. For example:

```css
label:has(~input){
  visibility hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Hi please hide me</label>
  <span>foo</span>
  <input type="text" name="bar"/>
</div>
<div>
  <label>dont target me</label>
</div>
```

But that does not work. What have I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo, you are missing the colon in your CSS.

`visibility hidden;` should be `visibility: hidden;`

```css
label:has(~input){
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Hi please hide me</label>
  <span>foo</span>
  <input type="text" name="bar"/>
</div>
<div>
  <label>dont target me</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Indeed without that typo works, but not in my actual code. I guess I have to make a better example